# Is there a 3D shape that is infinitely rotationally symmetrical in exactly 2 axis?

Tags: geometry, 3d, rotations, symmetry, rigid-transformation

A sphere is completely rotationally symmetrical in all directions. You can apply any combination of roll, pitch and yaw to it and it would be indistinguishable from the sphere you started with.

A cylinder is rotationally symmetrical along its "long" axis but if you rotate it in the other 2 directions, it becomes distinguishable from the original.

I am wondering if there exists a shape that has 2 axis of continuous rotational symmetry. A shape that could roll and pitch and be identical to the original but breaks symmetry if a yaw is applied.

Comment: When I try to visualize such a shape in my head, I'm torn between thinking it's impossible or it's some sort of very specific ellipsoid.

Comment: Do the two axes need to intersect at a fixed point?

Comment: My belief is that the answer is no, and that a proof can be found from showing that the rotations around any two fixed axes generate all rotations in 3-space.

Comment: @GregMartin That is very true but proving quite more than what's really needed. Let $a,b$ be two rotations along different axes. Conjugating $a$ by $b$ necessarily generates a rotation on a third axis.

Comment: Aha, true, that answers the question as asked (and one can even just compose the rotations rather than conjugating). I'll upvote if you write an answer!